# Angular4 - input types Validators from HTML5

Tags: html, validation, angular2-forms

In HTML5 I can specify

`<input class="form-control" type="url"  [formControl]="homepage" >`

which is of input-type url. If I use

`private homepage = new FormControl();`

I have my input-field but obviously no validator. To my understanding the field should be automatically validated in the browser (as HMTL5-element). But how to access the evaluation results?

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` elements with `type="url"` are not supported in Internet Explorer 9 (and earlier versions), or Safari.

this is demo
https://jsfiddle.net/truonghungit/6g9Lnen8/